# How to acknowledge poison pill in error handler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a requirement to process kafka messages in at-least-once fashion. Spring kafka supports async ack starting from 2.8 version. I am storing received offsets from kafka in a map and after message processing is done committing kafka offsets. This all working fine until i send any error event(poison pill). I am not able to commit bad record inside error handler and due to this kafka is not consuming any new records after encountering any bad/malformed record.

code for kafka listener factory:

```
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JsonNode> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, JsonNode> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JsonNode> factory =
                    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
            factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
            factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
            factory.getContainerProperties().setAsyncAcks(true);
            return factory;
        }
```

Error Handler Code:

```
  @Bean("errorHandler")
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        log.info("Creating error handler");
        return (thrownException, records) -> {
            log.error("Inside error handler");
        };
    }
```

This error handler does not have access to Acknowledgement object.
I created `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` which has access to Acknowledgement object. but on error KafkaListenerErrorHandler is not getting called.

code:

```
  @Bean("kafkaListenErrorHandler")
    public ManualAckListenerErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler() {
        return (message, exception, consumer, ack) -> {
            log.info("Inside manual ack error handler " + exception.getMessage());
            exception.printStackTrace();
            ack.acknowledge();
            return null;
        };
    }
```

in kafka consumer

```
  @KafkaListener(
            id="default_kafka_listener",
            topics = "topic",
            groupId = "groupId",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListener",
            errorHandler = "kafkaListenErrorHandler",
            autoStartup = "false")
   public void consume(@Payload JsonNode message)
```

Current spring boot version 2.7.8
spring-kafka version 2.9.5

How to acknowledge error messages in kafkaListenErrorHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`; deserialization errors will be sent to the `CommonErrorHandler`. With the `DefaultErrorHandler` and `Ackmode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, the error handler can be configured to ack recovered records.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer

```java
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * The container must be configured with
 * {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties.AckMode#MANUAL_IMMEDIATE}.
 * Whether or not the commit is sync or async depends on the container's syncCommits
 * property.
 * @param commitRecovered true to commit.
 */
@Override
public void setCommitRecovered(boolean commitRecovered) { // NOSONAR enhanced javadoc
    super.setCommitRecovered(commitRecovered);
}
```

The `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` will never receive these errors.